# Custom ringtones at the second WhatsApp account?

Tags: whatsapp-messenger, ringtone, samsung-dual-messenger

On my Galaxy A70 (dual SIM card) I installed via Dual Messenger a second WhatsApp account for my private SIM card. Unfortunately the new account contains only the default ringtones. How I can add the custom ringtones to this account?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can send the ringtone you want as mp3 or ogg file attached to a WhatsApp message from your primary WhatsApp account to your secondary Whatsapp account. In the secondary WhatsApp save it to the folder `Ringtones` on the internal sd-card section (should be path `/sd-card/Ringtones`).

Afterwards your system should be able to detect and use the saved ringtone. May be a reboot is required if the ringtone does not directly appear in the ringtone list.

Comment: After re-check and tests I have to state the following: The folder "Ringtones" in the internal sd-card section is not necessary for this problem! So I placed the folder "Ringtones" with the customized sounds inside the folder "DualApp", this folder appeared after the release of the second WhatsApp account inside the main root (internal storage). After that a reboot is necessary!